# How can I send an email, with an attachment from the user's local storage, using Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, attachment

I'm new to Google Script but quite experienced in Excel VBA. I'm trying to set up a Google Sheet to enable sending of a given document by email attachment to a number of recipients.
I've got the email part working, and I can see how to attach a doc such as a PDF from Google Drive, but I need to know how to offer the user a choice of files in his or her own local storage, i.e. on their own computer hard drive. It would be great if I could code something that offered the user a selection screen like MS Explorer from which they could select a file to attach. I realise this might not be immediately possible, and the file might have to be uploaded to Google Drive first. If so, it would be great to automate that too.
I'd really appreciate any help with this please.

Comment: Use Google Picker